# Angular Bootstrap $modal with active background elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a requirement to implement Bootstrap modal, (I use angular `$modal` service) where the background elements should remain active, i.e even with the modal open, the background DOM must be usable / clickable. I have tried setting `backdrop = false` in the `$modal` properties but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply hide modal overlay with CSS:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    display: none;
}
.modal {
    left: 50%;
    right: inherit;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: inherit;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

For this also make sure you add `backdrop: 'static'` to modal configuration to prevent modal close on body click.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/46M6F7BL9FtQqt9WiBuJ?p=preview

Comment: nope didn't work. I need the page operable over which the modal is rendered. i.e, if there is a button on the page over which the modal opens, I need to be able to click that button

Comment: Check updated answer, I added additional CSS rule, now it should work. Also check the demo.

Comment: Ok its working.. but the component from which the modal is being called is not responsive! :P Anyways, great improvement, thanks a lot! Can you now help me how to make it draggable?

Comment: To make it draggable you will need to use another directive. There are many of them, but this is worth separate question I think.

Comment: Ok. and I think your css having `width:100%` was not allowing me to click on the sides of the modal, I removed it and now it is working well.

Comment: Ok, it seems like I cannot post another question within a 90 min span. So can you please help me how to make this modal draggable?

Comment: Let me see, if I can find some directive easy to use.

Comment: Check this version with jQuery UI draggable wrapped into simple directive. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkGzCFNwtbZbeS5oqmq1?p=preview

Comment: yes I have seen that. But for it you need jquery ui as dependency. Now I am trying out a different [approach](http://plnkr.co/edit/8CHoiN?p=preview), if that fails then would use this :)

Comment: +1, But in the latest Boostrap 3, the backdrop element is removed if you don't set it. Therefore, you don't need `.modal-backdrop {
    display: none;
}`. However, you still need to adjust the `.modal` css just as you point out in the answer.